# Why laravel eloquont relation returning empty array

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-many

```
My Relationship is 

    public function QuestionOptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\QuestionOption','QuestionId');
    }

but when i am running this query 

        $builder = Question::select([
            'id', 'type', 'questionText', 'note', 'solutionText',
        ])->with('QuestionOptions')
        ->orderByRaw("RAND()")
        ->skip(0)
        ->take(1)
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

i am getting this 

    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "multiple",
        "questionText": "2 + 2 = ?",
        "note": null,
        "solutionText": null,
        "question_options": []
    },

so i want to know why i am getting question_options empty is there any problem in my query?
```

AFTER CHANGES :-

i tried to change my query and i removed select so now my query looks like this

```
        $builder = Question::with('QuestionOptions')
        ->orderByRaw("RAND()")
        ->skip(0)
        ->take(1)
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

after running the query my output is below i am getting all the fields of both the table which is OK but the problem arises now how i am supposed to get only specific fields

```
   [{
        "Id": 2,
        "UID": "123456789098765",
        "Type": "single",
        "Rank": 2,
        "QuestionText": "4 + 4 = ?",
        "TotalMarks": 5,
        "Note": null,
        "SolutionText": null,
        "Status": "active",
        "TimeStamp": "2020-11-17 12:04:18",
        "NegativeMark": 2,
        "TestId": 4,
        "question_options": [
            {
                "Id": 13,
                "OptionText": "5",
                "Rank": 1,
                "IsAnswer": "no",
                "Status": "deactive",
                "TimeStamp": "2020-11-17 12:59:14",
                "QuestionId": 2
            },]
```

Comment: What do the migrations look like? What are the names of the foreign key fields on questions and/or question_options?

Comment: my question table contains -> id,type,rank,questionText,totalMarks,status,testId 

my questionOption table contains -> id,optionText,rank,IsAnswer,status,questionId

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
       $builder = Question::with('QuestionOptions')
        ->orderByRaw("RAND()")
        ->skip(0)
        ->take(1)
        ->get(['id', 'type', 'questionText', 'note', 'solutionText'])
        ->toArray();
```

Comment: but questionId is not in table so it will throw error

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;QuestionId&#039; in &#039;field list&#039; (SQL: select `id`, `type`, `questionText`, `note`, `solutionText`, `QuestionId` from `test_question`

Comment: That was my bad you can specify the field's name in get(). You get only specific fields. Please see my updated answer. and try this one. I hope this is works.

Comment: thank you for your effort but it didn't help :(

Comment: actually problem arises when i try to get specifc column, i have tried same method without using select then i got all field from both tables